# Drupal template, verify that the page is a menu item

Tags: php, templates, drupal, menu, drupal-7

Helló!

I want to examine that the actual page is in the menu.
I want to do with drupal template (page.tpl.php).
For example:

```
if ($page_is_a_menuitem):
    echo "This page is in the menu";
else:
    echo "This page not in the menu";
endif;
```

Because if the page is in the menu a want to highlight the title.

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: I think you don't need to do it manually because Drupal gives you a class "active" on menu item if you are on the page.

Comment: try a new code . i hope it's better of old code and usefull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

this is return to a all menu list :- `menu_get_menus(true)`

like this

```
Array
(
    [menu-footer-menu] => Footer Menu
    [main-menu] => Main menu
    [management] => Management
    [navigation] => Navigation
    [user-menu] => User menu
)
```

and you want to get main menu inside a all list to use this

```
$tree = menu_tree_all_data('main-menu')
```

this is return in main-menu in all items

otherwise you use a this code

```
$path = current_path();
$selected_menu= '';
$menu = menu_link_get_preferred($path = NULL, $selected_menu = NULL);
```

`$menu` is return a current page manu detail after you want

```
echo "this menu is ".$menu['menu_name'] .' and menu title is '.$menu['title'];
```

Comment: This code is good, but I found a better solution. The final code here: `$menu = menu_navigation_links('main-menu');
function in_array_r($needle, $haystack, $strict = false) {     foreach ($haystack as $item) {         if (($strict ? $item === $needle : $item == $needle) || (is_array($item) && in_array_r($needle, $item, $strict))) {             return true;         }     }      return false; } echo in_array_r(current_path(), $menu) ? 'found' : 'not found';` This search the current page in the multidimensional menu array.

Comment: This code will scan all menus: `<?php
$menu = array();
$menuLinks = array();
$menus = menu_get_menus($all = TRUE);
foreach ($menus as $key => $value) {
 array_push($menu, menu_navigation_links($key));
}
foreach ($menu as $key => $value) {
 foreach ($value as $key => $value2) {
  array_push($menuLinks, $value2['href']);
 }
}
print current_path();
echo (in_array(current_path(), $menuLinks)) ? '<br>found<br>' : '<br>not found<br>';
?>`

Answer (score 1):

get the whole menu tree

```
$tree = menu_tree_page_data('primary-links');
```

and check in page tpl if the node id exists in the menu...